Serving static files with jupyterlab
I create a PDF file in a notebook and save it to disk.
When I try to download it via a link (<a href="{pdf_file}">Click here to download: {pdf_file}</a>) in the notebook I get a 404 not found error message.
it's because a /files/ folder is added to the url when the link is generated, but I don't know how to set it up, and creating a /files/ folder under the root is obviously not enough.
I have tried to specify folders in the jupyter_notebook_config.py file
by adding values such as :
c.ExtensionApp.static_paths = [os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'files')]
c.ServerApp.extra_static_paths = [os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'files')]
c.ServerApp.extra_static_paths = ['./files/']

In none of the cases, although the file is present in the indicated folder, can I download it.
What am I doing wrong?
Do you have an example that works?
my configuration:
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.1.1
ipykernel        : 6.9.1
ipywidgets       : 8.1.3
jupyter_client   : 7.4.9
jupyter_core     : 5.7.2
jupyter_server   : 2.14.1
jupyterlab       : 4.2.2
nbclient         : 0.5.11
nbconvert        : 7.16.4
nbformat         : 5.10.4
notebook         : 7.2.1
qtconsole        : 5.2.2
traitlets        : 5.14.3

Thanks

"it's because a /files/ folder is added to the url when the link is generated, ". I doubt that is the problem. What you are seeing when you hover is the endpoint for the API. It still should work to be able to open that file by clicking that link or downloading it by shift-right clicking on the link and choosing Save Link As.... Or something to that effect. To demonstrate, go here and click on the 'launch binder' badge to bring up a new temporary session on a remote machine. When the session comes up, make a new notebook and make a ...

 new markdown cell and put in that markdown cell <a href="runtime.txt">Click here to download: runtime.txt</a> and now run that cell. You'll see if you hover over the link there is /files/ in front of it in the URL. Clicking on it will open the content in the file editor view and the content is visible. If I want to download from the link and not the file browser, I do that by shift-right clicking on the link and choosing Save Link As.... All that work eventhough there is no files directory to speak of anywhere in the file/directory hierarchy. Feel free to explore ...

 using cd and ls in a terminal instance in that same session to prove that to yourself. (More on the endpoint  stuffhere](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/binderhub-api-endpoint-example-and-download-files/8455/5?u=fomightez).) So I don't believe the /files/ you are seeing is the issue & all I think you are doing to add files in jupyter_notebook_config.py may be making your situation worse.  Getting back to your real issue here though.... can you select the file in JupyterLab's file browser and right-click and choose Download and does that work?
